# Как сделать выпадающий список из цветов в WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

Нужен выпадающий список который будет отображать только цвет.

```
<ComboBox
                            Grid.Row="11"
                            Grid.Column="2"
                            Width="Auto"
                            Height="Auto"
                            MinWidth="100"
                            VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                            IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding ColorList}"
                            SelectedIndex="{Binding ColorSelect}"
                            SelectedValue="{Binding ColorSelectValue}"
                            SelectedValuePath="Id"
                            Text="variable">
                            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <Rectangle
                                            Width="16"
                                            Height="16"
                                            Margin="0,2,5,2"
                                            Fill="{Binding Name}" />
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                        </ComboBox>
```

ViewModel

```
private void GetColorId()
    {
        ColorCollection.Add(new ColorsServices(0, Colors.Black));
        ColorCollection.Add(new ColorsServices(1, Colors.Yellow));
        ColorCollection.Add(new ColorsServices(2, Colors.Green));
        ColorCollection.Add(new ColorsServices(3, Colors.Gray));
        ColorCollection.Add(new ColorsServices(4, Colors.PaleGreen));
        ColorCollection.Add(new ColorsServices(5, Colors.Violet));
        ColorCollection.Add(new ColorsServices(6, Colors.CadetBlue));
    }
private ObservableCollection<ColorsServices> ColorCollection = new ObservableCollection<ColorsServices>();
```

и Сервис

```
public class ColorsServices
{
    public ColorsServices(int id, Color name)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Color Name { get; set; }
}

public ObservableCollection<ColorsServices> ColorList
    {
        get { return ColorCollection; }
        set { ColorCollection = value; }
    }
```

На данный момент результат вот такой: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать что бы рядом со списком были отображены кружки с фоном данного цвета?

Comment: А какого типа ваш `ColorList`?

Comment: типа ObservableCollection<ColorsServices>, это свойство возвращающее ColorCollection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не вопрос. Предположим, что тип ваших item'ов — `ColorServices`. Тогда используем такой XAML:

```
<ComboBox Width="100" ItemsSource="{Binding ColorList}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ColorsServices}">
            <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                <Ellipse Height="15" Width="15" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                         DockPanel.Dock="Left">
                    <Ellipse.Fill>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Name}"/>
                    </Ellipse.Fill>
                </Ellipse>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="2"/>
            </DockPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Результат:

[image: trivial]

Comment: все работает, спасибо)

Comment: @IvanProdaiko: Пожалуйста!